# select option tag in ror?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, html-select

i am new at ror.

option select tag in rails

```
<%= select_tag(:city_id, '<option value="1">Lisbon</option>,<option value="2">Madrid</option>' %>
```

produces this html:

```
<select id="city_id" name="city_id">
    <option value="1">Lisbon</option>
<option value="2">hjkLisbon</option>
</select>
```

and option select tag

```
<%= select_tag(:city_id, options_for_select([['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2]])) %>
```

produces this html:

```
<select id="city_id" name="city_id">
<option value="1">Lisbon</option>
<option value="2">Madrid</option>
</select>
```

for second option select tag i am getting the dropdown with options but in first one i am not getting it, only dropdown is there in first one but no options.
can anybody please explain me why it is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have these two cities you can use normal html

```
<select id="city_id" name="city_id">
<option value="1">Lisbon</option>
<option value="2">Madrid</option>
</select>
```

If you fetch the cities from you database you can do

```
select_tag ‘city_id’, options_for_select(@cities.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] })
```

This would generate something like:

```
<select id="city_id" name="city_id">
  <option value="1">Lisbon</option>
  <option value="2">Madrid</option>
</select>
```

Do not be afraid to use html. The most simple solution is the best solution.

Comment: as i am new to rails, so i wanted to know why the first code does not work even though producing same html.

Comment: rails methods are really spesific about how you pass in options. select_tag is a rails method. The first way you send options to the select_tag method is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ref [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002239)

Change

```
<%= select_tag(:city_id, '<option value="1">Lisbon</option>,<option value="2">Madrid</option>' %>
```

To

```
<%= select_tag(:city_id, '<option value="1">Lisbon</option>,<option value="2">Madrid</option>') %>
```

You are not closing the select tag i.e. `)` is missing

Answer (score -1):

if you really want to keep selected the country name on edit page then..

```
<%= f.select :country, (country_name), :selected => @model.country %>
```

Where `country_name` is a method in helper.